# ionic 2 List Filter withouth searchbar

Tags: ionic2

I'm stuck here ,

I can filter my list with searchbar event.
But i want to filter list when i open the filter page  like this 
item.title = 'Hello'  what i must do to filter list without searchbar event ?

Home.html

```
      <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" [debounce]="500" 
placeholder="search..."></ion-searchbar>
```

in home.ts

```
 initializeItems() {
        this.items = this.todos;
      }


  getItems(ev: any) {
    // Reset items back to all of the items
    this.initializeItems();

    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
        return (item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: you mean set ion-searchbar value as "hello"? or filter the list contents in `ionViewDidLoad` lifecycle?

Comment: Filter the list contents in ionViewDidLoad lifecycle yes ,
I mean when the page opens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `initializeItems()` function and then use [`Array.Prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in `ionViewDidLoad` lifecycle hook to filter it same as in search..

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
 this.initializeItems();
 this.items = this.items.filter(item=>item.title=="hello");
}
```

Comment: Thank you again , for being helpful . It's working well now.

Comment: If you have the time, there is one last problem I have that prevents me from finishing here   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746581/get-user-info-mongodb-and-passport-in-ionic-2)

Comment: I would if I could but am not really familiar with passport.js